# Using Django ORM on Google Cloud SQL -No module named grizzled

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am able to connect to Google Cloud SQL service from my local machine:

```
    $ python manage.py syncdb
```

This command creates the required database tables on Google Cloud SQL using the django models. (My database settings point to Cloud SQL database settings)
However when I issue the **dbshell** command I get an error:

```
$ python manage.py dbshell

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/dbshell.py", line 21, in handle
    connection.client.runshell()
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/storage/speckle/python/django/backend/client.py", line 47, in runshell
    from google.storage.speckle.python.tool import google_sql
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/storage/speckle/python/tool/google_sql.py", line 53, in <module>
    from grizzled import db
ImportError: No module named grizzled
```

Is it possible to run ./manage.py dbshell on Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved it by adding the required google_appengine libraries to my PYTHONPATH.

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/google_appengine:/path/to/google_appengine/lib/django_1_5:/path/to/google_appengine/lib/grizzled:/path/to/google_appengine/lib/prettytable:/path/to/google_appengine/lib/sqlcmd:/path/to/google_appengine/lib/enum"
```

I have to do this everytime I want to connect to the Cloud SQL.

Comment: After months working with CloudSQL and django I started to see this problem. It was not needed before but now it is, any chance you know why?